# Trouble with passing generic in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm new to typescript, trying to achieve writing method with an generic type argument like in .Net.

Following the sample code :

```
class TestObject {
  Id: number;
  Truc: string;
  Machin: string;
}

export default
  {

    async FirstMethod(): Promise<TestObject> {
      return await this.TestMethodGen<TestObject>();
    },

    async TestMethodGen<T>(): Promise<T>  {
      // Json Deserialization other etc ...
      return <T>new Object();
    }
  }
```

How over type script error TS2347 occurs and i can't figure out why.

*TS2347 (TS) Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments.*

[image: VS Error]

Many thank for any help.

Comment: Does it help if you change `class TestObject` to `interface TestObject`?

Comment: @Clarity Thank tryed but problem still there :/

Comment: @JérémieLeclercq can't really reproduce the issue with the code provided https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuB5ARgK3sJ0DeAsAFDTQCSAJgIQBc0AdgK4C2a8ATgNzGmzuPBa0ZOwCW9AObcS0ALJhgAC3FCR4qcQC+xYvAAeABwD27XBXgAzMIxBIe+HTNKQAnvWDQAYqPbJZ8JEUjCgAKAEo6AAV2I2ZRCHgAHgRkdCwcAD4HJ1JodgDGdnpoMAB3MFFcQPiAOhSkf0DggHF4emTEVExsJAzw6VzoTQAaR0HXdzhOxqCKVvbYPojoaNj4pMXSQhzSAHpd6AApCCNigBFEDlEwEFEALzAkUVPoI0COaACPGp-7QfykIVikwQCAqH8hvZNEA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html).

> When creating factories in TypeScript using generics, it is necessary to refer to class types by their constructor functions.

The following works fine on my setup.

```js
class TestObject {
    Id: number;
    Truc: string;
    Machin: string;
}

export default {
    async FirstMethod(): Promise<TestObject> {
        return await this.TestMethodGen(TestObject);
    },

    async TestMethodGen<T>(c: { new (): T }): Promise<T> {
        // Json Deserialization other etc ...
        return new c();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you, i was too attached to the .Net style of passing generic type :)

Comment: You are very welcome! (and I mix this up all the time myself)